# MariaDB Select Into output file thinks file exists

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB on Centos7 and trying to `SELECT INTO` an outfile. For some reason, MariaDB seems to think that the file exists even though it most certainly doesn't. My query is

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE <condition> INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '/tmp/output.csv' already exists
```

But when I `ls -la` on `/tmp` there is most certainly not a file by that name.

Is there some magical place MariaDB stores this file (and re-maps `/tmp`)?! Or is something else going on here.

Comment: I would believe MariaDB.  One possibility is that it is running on a different server, so you can't really see the `tmp` directory.  And putting a file into `tmp` is likely going to run into naming conflicts, so you might put it in your user directory.

Comment: It is running on a VPS, what do you mean by a different server? An actual different machine or something virtualized by MariaDB?

Comment: . . The temporary directory is located on the machine where the MariaDB server is running.  You probably want to mount a more local disk to that machine and write the file over the network.